# Strange behavior of Stream.spliterator for parallel streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

I'm using the stream spliterator directly for the low-level operations in the library I'm writing. Recently I discovered very weird behavior when I take the stream spliterator and interleave `tryAdvance/trySplit` calls. Here's a simple code which demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Spliterator;

public class SpliteratorBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] input = { { 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }, { 9 } };
        Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = Arrays.stream(input).parallel()
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream).spliterator();
        spliterator.trySplit();
        spliterator.tryAdvance(s -> {});
        spliterator.trySplit();
        spliterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
5
6
9
```

As you can see, after flat-mapping I should get the ordered stream of consecutive numbers from `1` to `9`. I split the spliterator once, so it should jump to some intermediate location. Next I consume an element from it and split it one more time. After that I print all the remaining elements. I expect that I will have several consecutive elements from the stream tail (probably zero elements, it would also be fine). However what I get is `5` and `6`, then sudden jump to `9`.

I know that currently in JDK spliterators are not used this way: they always split before the traversal. However official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) does not explicitly forbid to call the `trySplit` after `tryAdvance`.

The problem was never observed when I use spliterator created directly from collection, array, generated source, etc. It's observed only if the spliterator was created from the parallel stream which had the intermediate `flatMap`.

So the question is: did I hit the bug or it's explicitly forbidden somewhere to use the spliterator in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see from the source of `AbstractWrappingSpliterator` and company, when you `tryAdvance`, the output of `flatMap` (4,5,6) gets buffered and then 4 gets consumed leaving (5,6) in the buffer.  Then `trySplit` correctly splits off (7,8) to the new `Spliterator` leaving 9 in old one but the buffered (5,6) stay with the old `Spliterator`.

So this looks like a bug to me.  It should either hand the buffer off to the new `Spliterator` or return `null` and refuse to split if the buffer is not empty.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of [`Spliterator.trySplit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--):

> This method may return `null` for any reason, including emptiness, **inability to split after traversal has commenced**, data structure constraints, and efficiency considerations.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the documentation explicitly mentions the possibility to attempt splitting after commencing traversal and suggests that spliterators which are unable to handle this may return `null`.

So for ordered spliterators, the observed behavior should considered a bug [as described by Misha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154460/2711488). Generally, the fact that `trySplit()` has to return a *prefix* spliterator, in other words, has to hand over all intermediate state regarding the next items to the new spliterator, is a peculiarity of the `Spliterator` API that makes bugs likely. I took this question as a motive for checking my own spliterator implementations and found a similar bug…

Answer (score 2):

This behavior was officially recognized as a bug (see [JDK-8148838](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148838)), fixed by me and pushed into JDK-9 trunk (see [changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/8719783940f1)). The sad thing is that my initial patch actually fixed the splitting after `flatMap` (see [webrev](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~tvaleev/webrev/8148838/r2/)), but this patch was declined as such scenario (using `trySplit()` after `tryAdvance()`) was considered as uncommon and discouraged. The currently accepted solution is to disable the `WrappingSpliterator` splitting after advance at all which is enough to fix the problem.