# Searching for certain string in certain position in own datatype Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made my own datatype (Person) ArrayList. It has first name, last name and year of birth. Like this:

```
Ben Dover 1998
Mike Long 1980
Mary Madrilla 2000
Anne McGee 1995
Artie Long 2004
```

How can I cycle through the list and search certain family name (like "Long") and then print out all people with this family name?

```java
personList.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getLastName().equals("Long"))
        .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.LastName));
```

This thing works. Now, how do I print out a message, when there isn't family name like that (etc "Smith")?

Comment: Use a for loop and a conditional statement?

Comment: Could be done like this: `personList.stream().filter(person -> person.getLastName().equals("Long")).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));`

Comment: @namenotfound That is so very readable for someone who (probably) just starts learning Java :)

Comment: I got it. But what should I add to print out "There is no family name like that." when there isn't a family name that I am searching for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special behavior of a stream if there are no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580446/special-behavior-of-a-stream-if-there-are-no-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find anything integrated for you in the lamda expression, but here is an alternative solution:

```
private static void printPersonsByLastName(String lastName, List<Person> personList) {
    List<Person> personsByLastName = personList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals(lastName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    String result = personsByLastName.isEmpty()
            ? String.format("Persons by last name '%s' couldn't be found!", lastName)
            : personsByLastName.stream().map(p -> p.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    System.out.println(result + "\n");
}
```

Method in context:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person ben = new Person("Ben", "Dover", 1998);
        Person mike = new Person("Mike", "Long", 1980);
        Person mary = new Person("Mary", "Madrilla", 2000);
        Person anne = new Person("Anne", "McGee", 1995);
        Person artie = new Person("Artie", "Long", 2004);

        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(ben,mike, mary, anne, artie);

        printPersonsByLastName("Smith", personList);
        printPersonsByLastName("Long", personList);
    }

    private static void printPersonsByLastName(String lastName, List<Person> personList) {
        System.out.printf("Print result of lastname '%s': %n", lastName);

        List<Person> personsByLastName = personList.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals(lastName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        String result = personsByLastName.isEmpty()
                ? String.format("Persons by last name '%s' couldn't be found!", lastName)
                : personsByLastName.stream().map(p -> p.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(result + "\n");
    }

}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int yearOfBirth;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int yearOfBirth) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getYearOfBirth() {
        return yearOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", yearOfBirth=" + yearOfBirth +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Persons by last name 'Smith' couldn't be found!

Next search on last name Long:
Person{firstName='Mike', lastName='Long', yearOfBirth=1980}
Person{firstName='Artie', lastName='Long', yearOfBirth=2004}
```